# Connect Entity Framework to Oracle 11g not working

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, web-config

I am creating a project that is the first time I am connecting to an Oracle database in an MVC project. I have found sources [here](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/) and [here](https://gregorbowie.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/connecting-to-an-oracle-database-from-microsoft-net/) that I followed the instructions to the letter, yet I still cannot get it to work.

**The Steps I have followed are:** 
1) Installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 
2) Installed Entity Framework version 6 
3) Referenced Oracle Libraries 
4) Added Oracle Provider to the Web config and app config of my project
5) Tried to add a new entity data model from database schema but the data provider for Oracle never shows up when setting up the data connection.

Here is my webconfig:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MinimumInventory" connectionString="Server=SQLServerName\ServerInstance;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ThirdWaveData" connectionString="Server=OracleServerName;Initial Catalog=databaseName; User Id=myID; Password=myPassword; Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</providers>
```

as you can see, I am also connecting to a SQL server, if that effects the solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to download the oracle 12 driver/client. Otherwise you need to install oracle on production server.

You reference the Oracle.DataAccess in your Database project.
[image]

Instead of ConfigurationManager you can use the following: https://github.com/codingfreak/cfUtils/blob/d0769751ac64e8a67aea028821bef2a270dc525c/Logic/Logic.Utils/Utilities/ConfigurationUtil.cs

My connection string in web.config looks like the following:

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="oracle" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PD)));User ID=MyUSER;Password=MyPassword;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```